# Soteria HttpMessageContext.setRegisterSession() not working as expected?

Tags: java, security, session, authentication, jakarta-ee

I have implemented a custom `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` subclass to provide authentication using the [Soteria/Java EE Security](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/soteria) framework.  I've got authentication working just fine.  However, I've noticed that when I call [`HttpMessageContext.setRegisterSession(String, Set<String>)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/security/enterprise/authentication/mechanism/http/HttpMessageContext.html#setRegisterSession-java.lang.String-java.util.Set-) to create a Java EE `Session`, the behavior is not what I would expect.  I am expecting that the authenticated identity be associated with the web `Session`, and my `AuthenticationMechanism`'s `validateRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, HttpMessageContext ctx)` method would not be called on subsequent requests.  What I am observing, however, is that `validateRequest()` is called on every request, even if the user has already authenticated successfully.

I am able to get the behavior I want using the `@AutoApplySession` annotation on my `AuthenticationMechanism` class, but that is not the behavior I want.  I'd like to choose whether or not to create a session based on the type of credential provided.

Is my understanding of the `setRegisterSession()` method incorrect?  Or is this a bug within Soteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@AutoApplySession` is the new way to do this in Soteria ([JSR 375](https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/whats-new-in-java-ee-security-api-10.html#34)). If it does not suit your needs (as you need to either remember the authenticated identity or re-authenticate for all requests during the same HTTP session based on some other credential info), `validateRequest` method will still be called, regardless of whether you call the `HttpMessageContext`'s`setRegisterSession` method or not. `HttpMessageContext.setRegisterSession` will make the container remember the credentials but will not reuse them automatically, you still need to make the container reuse the authentication identity by doing the same thing Soteria's `AutoApplySessionInterceptor` does. So in your class which implements `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` you should add the following code before your actual authentication logic is performed in the `validateRequest` method:

```
Principal userPrincipal = request.getUserPrincipal();

if (userPrincipal != null) {   
    httpMessageContext.getHandler().handle(new Callback[] { 
                new CallerPrincipalCallback(httpMessageContext.getClientSubject(), userPrincipal) }
            );

    return AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS; 
}
```

Also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30063982/6090993) by Arjan Tijms. Although it's about JASPIC not Soteria, but in this case I think it's relevant.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you're following the incorrect source you've look at this [IMPLEMENTATION](https://github.com/javaee/security-soteria/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/soteria/mechanisms/HttpMessageContextImpl.java).

```html
/*  (non-Javadoc)
 *  @see javax.security.authenticationmechanism.http.HttpMessageContext#setRegisterSession(java.lang.String, java.util.Set)
 */
@Override
public void setRegisterSession(String username, Set<String> groups) {
  Jaspic.setRegisterSession(messageInfo, username, groups);
}
```

Under the library location:

```
import org.glassfish.soteria.mechanisms.jaspic.Jaspic;
```

From the [mechanisms](https://github.com/javaee/security-soteria/tree/master/impl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/soteria/mechanisms).